# Contract Error: invalid transaction v, r, s values

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I've checked the answer [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/14599) and [here](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/19699) but no luck.

**System information**

```
$ geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.13-stable
Git Commit: cbc4ac264e9671898bff6ec7e434da3eca4bd273
Git Commit Date: 20200416
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.14
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=/app/go/
GOROOT=/app/goroot/
```

I try to deploy a contract using geth with these settings.

genesis.json

```
{
  "coinbase"   : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000001",
  "difficulty" : "2",
  "extraData"  : "",
  "gasLimit"   : "4712388",
  "nonce"      : "0x0000000000000042",
  "mixhash"    : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "parentHash" : "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "timestamp"  : "0x00",
  "alloc": {},
  "config": {
        "chainId": 15,
        "homesteadBlock": 0
    }
}
```

I deploy successfully on version 1.8.27-stable, 
but got `Error: invalid transaction v, r, s values` on 1.9.13-stable and after.

contract.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.6.0;
contract TestContract{

  function multilpy(uint a,uint b) public pure returns (uint) {
      return a * b;
  }
}
```

submit.js

```
var testcontractContract = web3.eth.contract([{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"a","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"b","type":"uint256"}],"name":"multilpy","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]);
var testcontract = testcontractContract.new(
   {
     from: web3.eth.accounts[0], 
     data: '0x608060405234801561001057600080fd5b5060b98061001f6000396000f3fe6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b506004361060285760003560e01c8063ec2f209914602d575b600080fd5b606060048036036040811015604157600080fd5b8101908080359060200190929190803590602001909291905050506076565b6040518082815260200191505060405180910390f35b600081830290509291505056fea2646970667358221220a696452af2a08e58acf37b86b57fa8e4de08cb5a33d1e550780d13d45671aa2664736f6c63430006010033', 
     gas: '4700000'
   }, function (e, contract){
    console.log(e, contract);
    if (typeof contract.address !== 'undefined') {
         console.log('Contract mined! address: ' + contract.address + ' transactionHash: ' + contract.transactionHash);
    }
 })
```

Does someone have the same problem?

Comment: Hey, this might be due to the fact you are using chain ID 15. Have you set `defaultCommon` to this chainID? This chainID is part of the signing of transactions to prevent vigilant actors replaying these transactions on chains with other chain IDs (i.e. other chains). See https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.4/web3-eth.html#defaultcommon

Comment: thanks for the answer, I tried to set my chainId by `web3.eth.defaultCommon = { customChain: {name: 'custom-network', chainId: 15, networkId: 15} }` and set networkid option on the command line like this `geth --datadir path/to/data --networkid 15 console`, but still no luck :<