# How to fix "Error: invalid transaction v, r, s values" when deploying a smart contract to a private blockchain?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, web3js, genesis, wallet-contracts

Whenever I try to deploy a smart contract, I get an error that says "`Error: invalid transaction v, r, s values`". I'm using the following genesis JSON:

```
{
  "config": {
    "chainId": 31,
    "homesteadBlock": 0
  },
  "nonce": "0x0000000000000033",
  "timestamp": "0x0",
  "parentHash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "gasLimit": "0x8000000",
  "difficulty": "0x100",
  "mixhash": "0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "coinbase": "0x3333333333333333333333333333333333333333",
  "alloc": {}
}
```

The genesis JSON is based on [this GitHub Gist](https://gist.github.com/dickolsson/e652b3d0e7bee55aa0a582d8a03900bf).

Then I run the following commands:

```
# Init the blockchain
geth init --datadir /tmp/data genesis.json

# Start "running" the blockchain
geth --datadir /tmp/data
```

In a new tab, I generate a new address:

```
geth attach --datadir /tmp/data --exec 'var wachtwoord = "correct paard batterij nietje"; personal.newAccount(wachtwoord);'
```

Then I mine some Ether using `miner.start()` and `miner.stop()`.

The contract:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: UNLICENSED
pragma solidity ^0.7.0;

contract MijnEersteContract {
    string internal constant groet = "hallo, wereld! :o";

    function groetDeWereld() public pure returns (string memory) {
        return groet;
    }
}
```

Compiling it:

```
$ solc --abi --bin MijnEersteContract.sol

======= MijnEersteContract.sol:MijnEersteContract =======
Binary:
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
Contract JSON ABI
[{"inputs":[],"name":"groetDeWereld","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]
```

Deploying using the instructions [here](https://medium.com/mercuryprotocol/dev-highlights-of-this-week-cb33e58c745f):

```
$ geth attach --datadir /tmp/data
> personal.unlockAccount(eth.coinbase, "correct paard batterij nietje", 3600);
> var mijnEersteContract = eth.contract([{"inputs":[],"name":"groetDeWereld","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}]);
> var byteCode = "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";
> var deploy = { from: eth.coinbase, data: byteCode, gas: 2000000 };
> var mijnEersteContractPartialInstance = mijnEersteContract.new(null, deploy);
```

Then I get the dreaded error:

```
Error: invalid transaction v, r, s values
    at web3.js:6347:37(47)
    at web3.js:5081:62(37)
    at web3.js:3021:48(134)
    at <eval>:1:63(7)
```

I've read literally dozens of blog posts and Ethereum.SE answers, and I just can't figure it out. [Setting `web3.eth.defaultCommon.customChain`](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/83039/contract-error-invalid-transaction-v-r-s-values#comment103170_83039) as recommended by @JBrouwer and trying to create a new partial instance (i.e. running the `mijnEersteContractPartialInstance` line a second time) also doesn't seem to help.

What am I doing wrong? And how can I fix this?

**Version information**

```
$ geth version
geth version
Geth
Version: 1.9.25-stable
Git Commit: e7872729012a4871397307b12cc3f4772ffcbec6
Architecture: amd64
Protocol Versions: [65 64 63]
Go Version: go1.15.6
Operating System: linux
GOPATH=
GOROOT=go
```

```
$ solc --version
solc, the solidity compiler commandline interface
Version: 0.7.5+commit.eb77ed08.Linux.g++
```

Comment: The contract doesn't have a constructor so try `mijnEersteContract.new(deploy)` instead.

Comment: Hi @Ismael, thank you for your comment. It doesn't resolve the issue, but it's good to know nonetheless.